# Linux: how do I deal with "GThread not available" although libgthread is installed

Tags: linux, error-handling, installation

I am trying to install `tagsistant` on my linux fedora 20 system, so I started to follow the install instructions text which says first do `./configure`. When I do so it fails with the message:

`configure: error: "GThread support not available. Please install libgthread"`

I had already installed `libgthread`, `glib` and `libfuse` in response to this and previous messages.

Neither `grep GTh` nor `grep libg`, on the `config.log` file listing, find anything. Is there a fix for the error? I have not listed the contents of `config.log` or the output from the screen, as these are very long, but I can extract any relevant details if that will help.

After further investigation I have found the source of the error message in `config`:

```
{ $as_echo "$as_me:${as_lineno-$LINENO}: checking for g_thread_init in -lgthread-2.0" >&5
$as_echo_n "checking for g_thread_init in -lgthread-2.0... " >&6; }
if ${ac_cv_lib_gthread_2_0_g_thread_init+:} false; then :
  $as_echo_n "(cached) " >&6
else
  ac_check_lib_save_LIBS=$LIBS
LIBS="-lgthread-2.0  $LIBS"
```

And discovered that g-thread is deprecated, so not in the package, see [g-thread-init deprecated](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/2.37/glib-Deprecated-Thread-APIs.html#g-thread-init)

So again, please can anyone suggest how I get round this?

---

On reflection I think I should have asked this question on the Unix and Linux site, please, how do I migrate it there, or: can someone do it for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tagsistant ./configure is a bit misleading in reporting missing dependencies. First, GThread support is provided by glib itself, so the output should suggest to install glib, not libgthread.

Moreover what you really have to install are library include files. Usually you can get them by installing the -dev or -devel version of the package. In RedHat/Fedora the second will fit:

`$ yum install glib-devel`

Do the same for other packages like DBI, FUSE and libextractor.